# One-To-Many Relation in Symfony 2 with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I've looked at literally tons of questions/answers on Stack Overflow and other places on the web, but cannot find a resolution to this problem.

Before I explain the problem, I have:

- stripped back my entities so that they only have the minimum attributes and methods
- have cleared the doctrine query cache / metadata cache
- dropped and recreated the schema
- checked my spelling

I have the following two entities:

```
<?php
namespace Docker\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Source
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project",inversedBy="sources")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $project;

}


<?php
namespace Docker\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Source", mappedBy="project")
   */
  private $sources;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->sources = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  public function getSources() {
    return $this->sources;
  }
}
```

So a many 'sources' can belong to one 'project'.

In my controller I have:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$project = $em->find('Docker\ApiBundle\Entity\Project', 1);
$sources = $project->getSources()->toArray();
```

I have tried lots of things but I always get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: project in /.../www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1577
```

Like I say, I know there are a lot of questions going around about this, but none of the accepted answers fix my problem.

This all looks pretty fundamental to using Doctrine2 so not sure what I am doing wrong - it could be something really obvious.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $project var not null ? Or when doing ->getSources()->toArray(); that crashes ?

Comment: $project var is not null, and yes - it is when I do `$sources = $project->getSources()->toArray();` in the controller that causes the exception.  If I take this out then it is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project",inversedBy="sources")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $project;
```

Remove:

```
@ORM\Column(type="integer")
```

from annotation.

Comment: Ah ha!  That is it.  It make sense as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If this is exactly your code, i dont see a namespace in your Project class. Try adding the namespace line "namespace Docker\ApiBundle\Entity;".
If this is the same folder no need for "use" but if it s part of other bundle or folder try putting a line like "use Docker\ApiBundle\Entity\Project;" 
in your Source class. I Hope it helps..

Otherwise :

```
<?php
namespace Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Source
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  private $name;


  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="sources")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
   */
  private $project;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set project
 *
 * @param integer $project
 * @return Source
 */
public function setProject($project)
{
    $this->project = $project;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get project
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getProject()
{
    return $this->project;
}
}


<?php
namespace Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Source", mappedBy="object", cascade={"all"})
   */
  private $sources;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->sources = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  public function getSources() {
    return $this->sources;
  }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

/**
 * Add sources
 *
 * @param \Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Source $sources
 * @return Project
 */
public function addSource(\Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Source $sources)
{
    $this->sources[] = $sources;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove sources
 *
 * @param \Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Source $sources
 */
public function removeSource(\Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Source $sources)
{
    $this->sources->removeElement($sources);
}
}
```

and little part of the controller:
    public function helloAction()

```
{
        $id = 1;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $project = $em->getRepository('Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Project')->find($id);

        $source1 = $em->getRepository('Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Source')->find(3);
        $source2 = $em->getRepository('Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity\Source')->find(5);
        $project->addSource($source1);
        $sources = array();
        $sources = $project->getSources();
        var_dump($sources);
        return ....
}
```

and this works just fine for me.

Comment: Good spot -  but it was just the formatting of the post that wasn't quite there.  I've updated it so that the namespace shows.

Comment: Ok - that's great - that works for me.  However... I guess some of the problem with libraries like Doctrine is the *magic*.  It seems to do a lot for you, so I would have thought that if I had already populated the database with sources for my project, then I wouldn't need to add them to the project entity using addSource?  I'm guessing I can do some postLoad event callback to do this automagically, but i'm not 100% sure (considering the other things it does) why I would need to do this.  Infact, i'm not sure why I even need to set the annotation in the first place?

Comment: thanks for your hard work on this, but @zelkjo's answer is correct.  In your response, I had to add the sources to the project, whereby on Zeljok's one, if the database is pre-populated, then it comes back with what I am expecting i.e. a populated source entity.  I've +1'd you - thanks again.

Comment: well it depends what you want to do, i added manually some sources and projects cause i didnt have any entity like that before. I thought you wanted to keep it as an integer, tried to use as much of ur code as possible. The annotation are used to map objects in ur database. You can use annotation, yml or xml to set up ur database. If u're not confident enough with anotations use the other solutions.